# MySQL data into FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

**EDIT 2**
I have the array at the correct format but nothing added to calendar:

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

I want to get data from mysql and display it on fullcalendar. I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
//Set error reporting on
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//Include connection file
require_once('global.php');

//Json and PHP header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$eventss = array();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];

    $search_date = "SELECT * FROM appointment INNER JOIN patient ON appointment.patient_id = patient.id WHERE appointment.id_logged = :id_logged";
    $search_date_stmt = $conn->prepare($search_date);
    $search_date_stmt->bindValue(':id_logged', $id_logged);
    $search_date_stmt->execute();
    $search_date_stmt_fetch = $search_date_stmt->fetchAll();
    $search_date_stmt_count = $search_date_stmt->rowCount();

    foreach($search_date_stmt_fetch as $row)
    {
       $events[] = array( 'title' => $row['patient_name'], 'start' => date('Y-m-d',$row['date_app']), 'end' => date('Y-m-d',$row['date_app']), 'allDay' => false);
       array_push($events, $event);

    }

    echo json_encode($event);
?>
```

The array that should be returned to fullcalendar so it can display it should be like:

```
'id'=>'value', 'title'=>'my title', 'start'=>...etc
```

But what the array I am seeing in the XHR is like:

[image]

Here is fullcalendar script (no errors at the console):

```
    <script>
        (function ($) { 
            $(document).ready(function() {

              $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                  eventSources: [

                    // your event source
                    {
                        url: 'fullcalendar/get-events.php',

                        error: function() {
                            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                        },
                        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
                        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
                    }

                    // any other sources...

                ]
            });

          });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: `fullcalendar/get-events.php` seems like its not the correct file.Another thing i notice is you are using $_SESSION but i cant see session_start(). Please post your php code for global.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `$event`, `$events` and `$eventss` (unused).

It should read :

```
foreach($search_date_stmt_fetch as $row) {
    $event = array( 'id' => $row['patient_id'], 'title' => $row['patient_name'], 'start' => date('Y-m-d',$row['date_app']), 'end' => date('Y-m-d',$row['date_app']), 'allDay' => false);
       array_push($events, $event);
}

echo json_encode($events);
```

Comment: Okay let me see it

Comment: Ok. See my 2nd edit. The array now in it's required format but nothing added to calendar

Comment: If that's your only event, it's no surprise nothing shows up on your calendar : the event length is zero!

Comment: so no data from MySQL and PHP to display. I should see my sql query ?

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is that that event, once loaded in the calendar, is not visible, since its length is nil. Actually, it could happen that the calendar engine simply removes it, being too short.
Just put something realistic in the database and see if it appears.

Comment: I just fixed it. I added the `$.fullcalendar` inside `success` function of `AJAX` and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have problem with array you are using and you dont have ID for event, it supposee patient id to b   I made some changes on your code please try it .

```
foreach($search_date_stmt_fetch as $row)
    {
       $event = array( 'id' => $row['patient_id'], 'title' => $row['patient_name'], 'start' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['date_app'])), 'end' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['date_app'])), 'allDay' => false);
       array_push($events, $event);

    }

    echo json_encode($events);
```

Comment: what is the value return from `$row['date_app']`

Comment: in my db is `DATE`

Comment: I changed into DATETIME. But please see my edit 2 on top of my question

Comment: So try to date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['date_app']))

Comment: Now the problem is Start and End are same

Comment: `'start' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['date_app'])).' 00:00:00', 'end' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['date_app'])).' 23:59:00'`

Comment: still the same. Can you use a teamviewer and see my code live ?

Comment: I am sorry for delay. Yes sure, this is my skype id developh. contact me if you still get this error

Answer (score 1):

*it depends on version of [full calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)* , there are two version v2 , v1

the required properties for the [event object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) is **title,start**

if you are working with version v2, u need to convert the date to [Moment](http://momentjs.com/), the version v2 is completely working on moment objects.

after getting the data from server, we can convert it like this

```
in js file:

$.map(data, function (me) {
              me.title = me.title, // this is required
              me.start = moment(me.start).format();  // this is required
              me.end = moment(me.end).format(); 
 }

 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);
```